# Spring DATA REST generated endpoints not appearing in actuator mappings

Tags: spring-data

I am not seeing the runtime proxy mappings listed when accessing http://localhost:8080/mappings.  The endpoints work, however, they are not appearing in the mappings list.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known and rather old issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4541